# Use a custom thousand separator in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, text-formatting

I'm trying not to use the ',' char as a thousand separator when displaying a string, but to use a space instead. I guess I need to define a custom culture, but I don't seem to get it right. Any pointers?

eg: display 1000000 as 1 000 000 instead of 1,000,000

(no, `String.Replace()` is not the solution I'd like to use :P)

Comment: What's wrong with using String.Replace()?

Comment: @Jon B - because Replace wouldn't be culture independent. What if your running on a computer where the thousand sep is . ?

Comment: and since I'm already formatting the number, it'd be cluttering the code

Comment: @Peter - I belive you could use InvariantCulture and then do String.Replace(). I'm not arguing this as a good solution, I was just curious why the OP was opposed to it.

Comment: Because it is a hack?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I suggest you find a [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) which most closely matches what you want (i.e. it's right apart from the thousands separator), call [`Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.clone.aspx) on it and then set the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) property. (If you're going to format the numbers using currency formats, you need to change [`CurrencyGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator.aspx) instead/as well.) Use that as the format info for your calls to `string.Format` etc, and you should be fine. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

        Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("n", nfi)); // 12 345.00
    }
}
```

Comment: That Skeet brand LoadBalancer has routing issues?

Comment: This helps me out massively. Superb!

Answer (score 9):

Create your own [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(VS.71).aspx) (derivative) with a different thousand separator.

Answer (score 7):

There's a slightly simpler version of Jon Skeet one :

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberGroupSeparator = " ", NumberDecimalDigits = 0};

        Console.WriteLine(12345678.ToString("n", nfi)); // 12 345 678
    }
}
```

And the 'nfi' initialization could be skipped and put directly as parameter into the ToString() method.

Comment: That's basically John Skeet's answer rewritten. Not exactly creative or shorter!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way...

```
num.ToString("### ### ### ### ##0.00")
```

Comment: Although this works it will actually produce spaces in front of the number. For example the number 1 would have 4 spaces in front of it. So at least you will have to trim it. I think the best solution is to adjust the NumberFormatInfo if you want to override the Culture default format.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to

- have space as a thousand separator,
- have up to two decimals and
- optionally be negative.

This code solves it:

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"(^|(?<=-))\s*");
var format = "### ### ### ### ##0.##";
decimal number = 123456789.54m;
var str = regex.Replace(number.ToString(format), ""); // str = "123 456 789.54"
```

Here are examples of how this behaves for various numbers:

```cs
regex.Replace(0m.ToString(format), "")
"0"
regex.Replace(123m.ToString(format), "")
"123"
regex.Replace(123456789m.ToString(format), "")
"123 456 789"
regex.Replace(123456789.1m.ToString(format), "")
"123 456 789.1"
regex.Replace(123456789.12m.ToString(format), "")
"123 456 789.12"
regex.Replace(123456789.1234m.ToString(format), "")
"123 456 789.12"
regex.Replace((-123456789.1234m).ToString(format), "")
"-123 456 789.12"
regex.Replace((-1234m).ToString(format), "")
"-1 234"
regex.Replace((-1m).ToString(format), "")
"-1"
```