# How to insert a thousand separator (comma) with convert to double

Tags: c#, label

I am trying to format the contents of a text box:

```
this.lblSearchResults1.Text =
    Convert.ToDouble(lblSearchResults1.Text).ToString();
```

How do I amend this so that I the text includes comma/thousand separators?

i.e. 1,000 instead of 1000.

Comment: Look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752145/use-a-custom-thousand-separator-in-c

Comment: I also found this quite useful http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For complete custom control, use `... .ToString("#,##0.00")` or variations thereof.  The `.` and `,` will be replaced by culture dependent symbols. In most of europe you'd get 1.234,56.
Another useful picture is `0.0#`.

To use a pattern depending on the users (or on a selected) culture, use  [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString), as in `.ToString("N")` or `"... {0:N}"`.

Comment: I'm following this approach, but I get reversed result on Windows Server 2012, `530000` becomes `000,530`

Comment: Research that thoroughly and then maybe post a separate question with a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include the computer's culture settings.

Answer (score 92):

Looking at the [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings):

You can most easily use 'N' which will do the right thing based on the user culture, so in your case you can just add "N" as a param to the ToString

```
([double]12345.67).ToString("N")
```

> 12,345.67

Comment: This answer is slightly better than ToString("#,##0.00"), which works the same and also respects different thousand-separators in different cultures (e.g. "." in Germany and "'" in Switzerland). But ToString("N") makes it clearer that format might be culture-specific.

Comment: Respecting individual culture on this one gets the win for me. However, what about displaying an integer as an integer, rather than a float?

Comment: Answer is "N0", where 0 is the number of decimal places. "N1", "N2" ,etc would work.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do it would be something like:

```
Convert.ToDouble("1234567.12345").ToString("N")
```

If you want to control the decimal places you can do something like:

```
Convert.ToDouble("1234567.12345").ToString("N3")
```

In general look at the overloads on ToString for more exciting possibilities.

Comment: (Int32.Parse("78956258")).ToString("N0") -- Keep it simple !!

Comment: @JG'sSpark: I'm not sure what point you are making... That seems the same as I have in my answer, not simpler really...

Answer (score 10):

If you take a closer look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) you can try one of the following:

```
.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
.ToString("n", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to the above mentioned responses would be to use

```
this.lblSearchResults1.Text = String.Format("{0:N}", Convert.ToDouble(lblSearchResults1.Text))
```

If you wanted decimal places, just enter the amount of decimal places you wish to have after the N. The following example will return the value with 2 decimal places.

```
this.lblSearchResults1.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDouble(lblSearchResults1.Text))
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 3):

> double.Parse(Amount).ToString("N");

Answer (score 3):

Do not cast integral to double to do this!
Use NumberFormatInfo helper class, e.g:

```
    var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo() {
        NumberDecimalDigits = 0,
        NumberGroupSeparator = "."
    };

    var i = 1234567890;
    var s = i.ToString("N", nfi); // "1.234.567.890"
```