# Set Numbering Format of C# application to Indian numbering System

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, numbers

I have many classes with int, decimal variables in my C# application.
Consider the following example.

```
public class Employee
{
    decimal TotalSalary;
    public decimal Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return TotalSalary;
        }
        set
        {
            TotalSalary = value;
        }
    }
    public string GetSalary()
    {
        return TotalSalary.ToString();
    }

}

public class Contract
{
    Employee emp1 = new Employee();

    public void ProcessSalary()
    {
        emp1.Salary = 100000;
        SendToLabel(emp1.GetSalary());
    }
}
```

In the above example whenever I use **"ToString"** of any decimal/int variable in my application, it should give me the number in Indian numbering format like below.

100000 should render as 1,00,000

10000 should render as 10,000

This should happen globally in my C# .NET application.
Can I do this using CultureInfo in global.asax page.

Right now for formatting date i am using the following code.

```
 CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a thousand separator (comma) with convert to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456926/how-to-insert-a-thousand-separator-comma-with-convert-to-double)

Comment: `100000 should render as 1,00,000` are you sure that you don't want `100,000` as output?

Comment: Yes yes sure. 10000000 should render as 1,00,00,000.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whenever I use "ToString" of any decimal/int variable in my application,  it should give me the number in Indian numbering format

You could also make a new method as extension for the types `decimal` and `int`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string MyOutput(this decimal number)
    {
        return number.ToString("#,#.##", new CultureInfo(0x0439));
    }

    public static string MyOutput(this int number)
    {
        return number.ToString("#,#", new CultureInfo(0x0439));     
    }       
}
```

All [culture codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) for further reference.

Then you can use it throughout your programm for variables of the `decimal/int` types:

```
public string GetSalary()
{
    return TotalSalary.MyOutput();
}
```

Output: for `decimal asd = 1000000.23m;`

> 10,00,000.23

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this is what I need.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar you are very welcome. Unfortunately you cannot override the `ToString` method. But this is what the extension methods are there for

Comment: Yes, got it, As a one time job, i will replace all my ToString() of int and decimal variables in the entire application.

Answer (score 3):

Following code will be useful to you,

```
public string GetSalary()
{
    CultureInfo inr = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    return string.Format(inr, "{0:#,#}", TotalSalary);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, Is there a way to hide rupee symbol from that string.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. That will remove rupee symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `GetSalary` will be like this:

```
public string GetSalary()
{
    return String.Format("{0:n}", TotalSalary);
}
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rW1L5h)

You can use `"{0:n3}"` if you want to round off decimals to `3` digits.

Comment: I tried that, 10000000 should render as 1,00,00,000.00 but it gives me 10,000,000.00. Also I want to know how this can be done globally, Is there a way where I can override the decimal variable's "ToString()" function, or can this be defined in global.asax file using CultureInfo. I need this because there are many classes with int and decimal varibales throughout my application.