# c# add decimal points to string of integer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string "123456" and I want to make it "123.456". Is there a function in c# that converts the value to what I need?

Other examples: 
"1000000" -> "1.000.000"

Comment: If you had a number you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456926/how-to-insert-a-thousand-separator-comma-with-convert-to-double).

Comment: What you have is a string.  If what you want is an `int` or a `long` or something of that nature then you can use `int.TryParse()` or `long.TryParse()` or something of that nature.

Comment: Is that `.` a thousands separator in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: It is a thoousand separator indeed, but with a point

Comment: convert to long and then use the answer in the suggested duplicate

Comment: Parse it to integer and then use ToString with the desired [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First parse it to numeric type (depending what would be the length of your string), for example lets use `long` (and [`long.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx) method):

```
string str = "1000000";
long num = 0;
long.TryParse(str, out num); //or long.TryParse(str, out long num); in c# 7
```

then use `ToString()` to convert it back to string using specified format:

```
string nstr = num.ToString("N0");
```

Some article about numeric string formats: **[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)**

Comment: Do not use `TryParse`, if you ignore its return value. There is a `Parse` method for such case.

Comment: @Vladislav: Unless you're not interested in the return value, but are interested in quietly ignoring invalid input.  `TryParse` is a perfectly valid tool to use.

Comment: @David ignoring its return value is not correct, until you don't want to fallback to some default value. And you don't have meaningful defaults in the scenario discussed.

Comment: @Vladislav: *"ignoring its return value is not correct"* - Perhaps not in *your* use cases.  But there exist use cases outside of *your* use cases.  The OP isn't asking about defaults or handling invalid input.  That's up to *his* use cases.  `TryParse` is a tool.  And like any tool, it has valid uses.  This is one of them.  Just because something isn't correct *for your needs* doesn't mean it isn't correct *for all needs*.

Comment: @David this is not about *my* use cases, this is about advices considering correctness.

Comment: @Vladislav I don't think, that not using method's return value is something incorrect. I can bring lot of examples, when return value of method doesn't matter, it depends on situation. I'm not familiar with OP's situation, I don't know how will he get that string numbers, what would be that numbers (int, double, float), how will he use them after, but in fact I gave him some sort of example (also link to `TryParse` MSDN page), so he can decide what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by just making a call to a function :

```
private string AddSeparator(string value)
{
   string newvalue = string.Empty;

   try
   {
      newvalue = Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString("N");
   }
   catch
   {
      //Do whatever you want if conversion fails
   }

   return newvalue;
}
```

Comment: `Convert` class should be used for conversions only if types are not known at compile time. For other cases there is a `Parse` method. `Int32.Parse` for example.