# Implementation of a "," in a score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, number-formatting

I have created a basic score system and every time the player gives a correct answer for example gets 500,000 thousand added to their bank. I wanted to find out how I can have the money laid out as follows.From 0 to 999 normal no "," but when it goes over 999 it would then do 1,000 all the way to 10,000,000,000 and also for it to do the reverse so deduct the "," if under the amount. This is to make it easy on the player and it looks batter in my opinion so if there is a post with such an answer would be appreciated(Could not find from research) and ahead of time apologize for if this is a case of a re-post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a thousand separator (comma) with convert to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456926/how-to-insert-a-thousand-separator-comma-with-convert-to-double)

Comment: Thank you just could not find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language?  In C#:
`score.ToString("#0,000");`

Comment: It is in c# and found the answer here from bolov above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString

Comment: In Java, the same implementation exists. It is called `DecimalFormat`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use c#, How about this?

```
// it will be 123,456,789.123
string s = string.Format("{0:n3}", 123456789.123);
```

There are examples from the article of the N format on MSDN

```
double dblValue = -12445.6789;
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays -12,445.68
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N1", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")));
// Displays -12 445,7

int intValue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 123,456,789.0
```