# String.Format C# spacing between every 1000 number

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a custom thousand separator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752145/use-a-custom-thousand-separator-in-c-sharp)

I want a string format to format my numbers like this:

```
Input: 1000 Ouput: 1 000.00
Input: 10000 Output: 10 000.00 
Input: 100000 Output: 100 000.00
```

Comment: amazingly that none of the yet provided answers will work for 1 billion without extra effort. Go for John Skeets answer in the above link.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 4):

Perfectly working as per you need no need of extra formating

```
String.Format("{0:# ###.00}", 40000);
output - "40 000.00"
String.Format("{0:# ###.00}", 400000);
output - "400 000.00"
String.Format("{0:# ###.00}", 4000);
output - "4 000.00"
```

Check Blogpost about this : [**Format Number To Display**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/06/format-number-to-display.html)

Comment: Except the OP wants 2 decimal places...

Comment: won't work for values larger than 1 million

Comment: @TrevorPilley - its already updated ..just run the code this will work for sure

Comment: @woni - its working perfecly for th einput given by user ...i dont think that its not going to work for any number show the example error if you find any ...

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
String.Format("{0:### ### ### ###.##}", 10000.00)
```

**Result:**

```
"  10 000.00"
```

You will need to trim the result to remove the extra spaces

Comment: since this is the only answer here that works, even you have to trim the output: +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `NumberFormatInfo` class. look at the sample code.

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();          
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

int a = 1000;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("n", numberFormatInfo)); // 1 000.00
```

Comment: Guess you and I had the same idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go friend:

```
var formatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
formatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ";
formatInfo.CurrencySymbol = string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine(1000.ToString("C", formatInfo));
Console.WriteLine(10000.ToString("C", formatInfo));
Console.WriteLine(100000.ToString("C", formatInfo));
```