# Adding a word in the middle of a value by using StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I met this problem today , by using binding ; I could binding a number of values in a xaml file , the value looks like `58000.1234 , 58000.2234 , 58431.100` etc. I want to add a word in the middle of this value , which it could turn out to be `58x000.1 ,58x000.2, 58x431.1`

I found `StringFormat` could be a good method for dealing my problem , so I somehow tried this following code ,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat='{}{0:0.#}'}" />
```

it manage the point value problem , but i still don't know how to add the x in the middle of my values .

```
StringFormat='distance {0:0.#} m'
```

This code can add words before and after value .

Comment: You might be able to change the value of the thousands seperator to 'x' in a custom Culture. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752145/use-a-custom-thousand-separator-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string format like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='{}##x###.#'}" />
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, just add it to the format:

```
string.Format("{0:000 hello 000.00}", 123456);
//123 hello 456.00
```

Bear in mind that the zeros here are placeholders for values from right to left.  This is useful for formatting phone numbers too.

```
string.Format("{0:(000) 000-0000}", 8885551212);
//(888) 555-1212
```

Lastly, you can also use the hash (#) mark for a placeholder as well.

Here's the full documentation:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot divide the value. You will have to use an ValueConverter in the Binding.

```
 public class WordSplitConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string input = value.ToString();
            // you can parameterize the split position via the ConverterParameter
            string left = input.Substring(0,2);
            string right= input.Substring(2,input.Length-3);
            return string.Format("{0}X{1}",left ,right);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
<local:WordSplitConverter x:Key="wordSplitConverter" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource wordSplitConverter}" />
```

Please add the approriate error handling... ;)

Comment: Getting the value back in case of two-way binding may be tricky with converter approach. In that case it's better to use format string.

Comment: @AndreiZubov, well at least its possible. With a string format you need to enter it in its original form. But no problem, because the binding in the original code is against a textblock -> therefore OneWay. :)